# Eigenvalues of block matrix with a zero diagonal block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

I'm stuck on finding the eigenvalues of
$$
\bar{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & S\\
S^\top & A
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Both $S$ and $A$ are square matrices of the same dimension and are invertible. $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Any help is appreciated. :-D

Comment: I'm afraid not much can be said in such generality. Do you know *anything* about those matrices?

Comment: This isn't what's usually referred to as a block triangular matrix -- that would mean that the off-diagonal block is zero, not the diagonal block.

Comment: A better description might be that your matrix is "block antitriangular". In any event, is $\mathbf A$ (the $2,2$ block) symmetric?

Comment: hmm, in my problem $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: You should have mentioned that to begin with, you know.

Answer (score 1):

We have for block matrices, with $A$ invertible, that 
$$\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=\pmatrix{A&0\\ C&I}\cdot\pmatrix{I&A^{-1}B\\0&D-CA^{-1}B}.$$
In our case, when $\lambda\neq 0$, we get
$$\det(\overline A-\lambda I_{2n})=(-\lambda)^n\det(A-\lambda I_n-S(\lambda)^{-1}I_nS^T)=\det(\lambda^2I_n-\lambda A+SS^T).$$
This formula is also true for $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Here, I think you need the version where $\mathbf D$ is the one inverted, not $\mathbf A$...

Comment: I computed the determinant of $\overline A-\lambda I$, for $\lambda\neq 0$, hence we get that the matrix on the top left is invertible.